# How to setup cancancan abilities

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancancan, rolify

Having trouble figuring out how to set up my different roles with cancancan abilities. I have a model "Business" which has many users with a role of either :owner, :manager or :employee.
Im trying to make it first that if they don't belong_to that business they can't see anything for that business.  And second I want to limit functionality based on which role they have.

I guess I could do this within the views by using if statements and only showing them the things they have access to, but wondering if there is a better way with cancan

Comment: can you add code of what you have tried and doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- inside your ability.rb

  ```
  class Ability
    include CanCan::Ability

    def initialize(user)
      alias_action :create, :read, :update, :destroy, :to => :crud
      if user
          if user.role == "manager"
              can :crud, Business, :id => user.business_id 
              # this will cek whether user can access business instance (id)     
          elsif user.role == "owner"
              can :manage, :all
          end
      end
    end
  end
  ```

inside your controller you can do checking with 2 ways

1. step 1: with load_and_authorize_resource, this will automatically check all 7 rails method

   ```
   class BookingsController < ApplicationController
     load_and_authorize_resource 
     # this before filter will automatically check between users and resource
     # rails method here
     def show
     end
   end
   ```
2. step 2: check manually with authorize inside each method

   ```
   def show
     @business = Business.find(params[:id])
     authorize! :read, @business
   end
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Definitely read through [cancan's wiki](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities) as I'm not 100% on this, but I think the solution will look something like this:

```
def initialize(user)
  user ||= User.new

  if user.has_role?(:owner)
    can :read, Business, Business.all do |business|
      business.id == user.business_id
    end
  elsif user.has_role?(:whatever)
    # etc
  end
end
```

Then just check `authorize!` in the controller in the normal cancan way. As for showing them appropriate functionality in views, you can either do a bunch of if statements in the view any maybe try to use partials to make it all look palatable, or check in the controller and render different views based on role, but yeah, there's gotta be if statements somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to always use "incremental" permissions. Consider that cancancan starts already with the assumption that your users have no right on `Business`, so you can give them "incremental" permissions based on their role.

An example would be:

```
# give read access if they have any role related to the business
can :read, Business, users: { id: user.id }
# give write access if they are manager
can [:edit, :update], Business, business_users: { role: 'manager', user: { id: user.id } }
# give destroy permissions to owners
can [:destroy], Business, business_users: { role: 'owner', user: { id: user.id } }
```